# Rails 4: redirect_to without host (path only)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, host

A client forwards his domain (`www.client.com`) to my app (`www.host.com`) via a proxy method.
This works fine for links and everything, but not for redirections.

```
http://www.client.com
redirect_to '/test'

http://www.host.com/test
```

Is there a way to use `redirect_to` without the host, with a `path_only` option or something like that?

Thank you!

Comment: just type it as a string `redirect_to "/test"`http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html

Comment: `redirect_to url_helper_ending_with_path` is not working for you? (not `users_url` but `users_path` for example?)

Comment: Thanks, it's a string, but Rails prepends the host automatically: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb#L22